# Clean example of Bootstrap Alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have alert divs like this:

```
<div class ="alert-container">
    <div class="alert alert-failure alert-fixed" id="failure-alert">
    <strong><span id="failure-message"></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-fixed" id="success-alert">
        <strong><span id="success-message"></span></strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I am calling them like this

```
 <div id="lightsButtons" class="btn-group btn-toggle" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default lights-button" id=lights_on value="ON">ON
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default lights-button" id=lights_off value="OFF">OFF
      </button>
 </div>
```

JQuery:

```
$("#lights_on").click(function () {
    $.getJSON("/lights_on", function (data) {
        if (data.success == true) {
            $("#lightsState").text(data.lights_state);
            $("#success-alert").show();
            $("#lghts_on").addClass('active');
            $("#lights_off").removeClass('active');
            $("#success-message").text(data.success + data.state)
            $("#success-alert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(1000, function () {
                $("#success-alert").slideUp(1000);
            });
       } else {
            $("#failure-alert").show();
            $("#failure-message").text(data.success + data.state)
            $("#failure-alert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(1000, function () {
                $("#failure-alert").slideUp(1000);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

but all this is just a crappy mishmash of googled code and I really just want to see a clean way to do the following:

I want to have 2 buttons. When either of the buttons is pressed, it performs a .getJSON(/example) and gets a result.

For example lets use a boolean and a string. The result doesn't matter much for this situation. If True, it generates an alert that is already defined in the html file without any contents.

Alert will contain the result and the following behavior:

- Centered horizontally
- Slightly off (20px) the top of the page
- Floating above content and follows the page as it scrolls
- Fades in and, after a short time, fades out.
- Has a close button that can't be triggered multiple times while
  waiting for a result

Comment: So what is the problem exactly? Are you just looking for a cleaner way or do you have a problem with your existing source code?

Comment: Might I suggest getting yourself a JSFiddle account and "fiddling" with the code until you get your desired result?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, DevIshOne, very helpful.
your profile is an interesting read

Comment: and yes, NewToJS, I am looking for a cleaner way that synthesizes the attributes together. I have found and tried to use different peoples examples for individual attributes, but I have encountered trouble trying to combine them together, and I dont think my code works at all or has most of what I want-- I am just showing it for contextual purposes

Comment: interesting to see you chose to remove the racist text from your profile, DevIshOne.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a quick Codepen: https://codepen.io/MarkRabey/pen/KqKpWx

I didn't strictly follow your style suggestions, but it might give you an idea. I just used a random number to fake the ajax call and get either a success or error to show different alerts.

**Note** this doesn't use any of Bootstraps built in functions for alerts. I didn't look at those at all.

The JS:

```
// When called sets the buttons disabled depending if the lights are on or off
const toggleButtonState = function() {
    onButton.attr('disabled', lightsOn);
    offButton.attr('disabled', !lightsOn);
}

// show the alert by passing in type (success || error) and  message
const showAlert = function (type, msg) {
  alert.hide();
  alert.removeClass('alert--error alert--success');
  alert.addClass(`alert--${ type }`);
  alert.text(msg);
  alert.fadeIn(300, function() {
    $(this).delay(1200).fadeOut(300);
  });
}

// call ajax, toggle lightsOn on success
const toggleLights = function() {
  let toggleSuccess = false;

  // dummy for 'success'
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  if (random % 2) { // success
    lightsOn = !lightsOn;
    toggleSuccess = true;
    showAlert('success', `The lights are ${ lightsOn ? 'on' : 'off'}`);
  }

  toggleButtonState();
  showAlert(toggleSuccess ? 'success' : 'error', `The lights are ${ lightsOn ? 'on' : 'off' }`);
}

const alert = $('#alert');
const onButton = $("#lights_on");
const offButton = $("#lights_off");
let lightsOn = false;
toggleButtonState();

alert.hide();
onButton.click(toggleLights);
offButton.click(toggleLights);
```